# SslStream ignoring SslProtocols on linux - always using TLS v1

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tls1.2, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a asp net core 5.0 app running on linux on elastic beanstalk (MongoDB driver 2.12.4).

The MongoDb is version 4.0 and has a minimum TLS Protocol version of TLS 2.1 and above.

The application was working fine with AMI ".NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2" v2.1.5 however, after an update to v2.2.1 the application is unable to connect to MongoDB returning the following error.

```
A timeout occurred after 3000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx-shard-00-00.xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/connectionissue-shard-00-00.ybc5n.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|182_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:06.9903249Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:06.9903259Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxx/xxxx-shard-00-01.xxxx.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/connectionissue-shard-00-01.ybc5n.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|182_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:07.0047845Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:07.0047854Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxxx/xxxx-shard-00-02.xxxx.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "xxxx/xxxx-shard-00-02.xxxx.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|182_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:07.0124176Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-29T09:13:07.0124185Z" }] }.
```

To test, I created a simple test harness and deployed it to a new beanstalk application and created 2 environments with the two different AMIs.  This replicated the issue as expected.

The .NET version on the old image is `5.0.5` and `5.0.7` on the new.  I didn't find anything in the release notes of [5.0.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-may-2021/) or [5.0.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-june-2021/) to suggest any breaking behaviour.  Looking at GitHub,
there are no differences in SslStream between these 2 releases - [5.0.5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.5/src/libraries/System.Net.Security/src/System/Net/Security/SslStream.Implementation.cs) [5.0.7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.7/src/libraries/System.Net.Security/src/System/Net/Security/SslStream.Implementation.cs)

Running a packet capture shows that the old image uses TLSv1.2 which works as expected and the old version uses TLSv1 which gets rejected by the database (as you would expect).

[image: working]

[image: broken]

OpenSSL is the same version on both servers (1.0.2-fips) and the openssl.cnf is identical too.

There are no differences in the output of `printenv` either.

The new AMI image seems to be doing the opposite of [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux)

Making requests normal web requests use TLS 1.2 in both environments using curl and in code with HttpClient.

I have raised this with Amazon and they think it's a code issue with either the mongo driver or net core.

I can't find any way to explicitly force the mongo driver to use a specific TLS cipher.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

---

Edit

---

After looking through the code in the Mongo Driver I simplified their code and re-created the issue without the driver.

I created this test method to reproduce the issue and explicitly set SslProtocols to TLSv1.2.

```
    private string SslTest(string hostname, int port)
        {
            var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);

            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip.First(), port);
            
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            using var stream = new NetworkStream(socket, true) {ReadTimeout = 3000, WriteTimeout = 3000};
            using var sslStream = new SslStream(stream);
            
            var targetHost = hostname;
            var clientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(targetHost, clientCertificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                sslStream.Close();
            }
            
            return $"stream opened and closed successfully to {hostname}:{port}";
        }
```

Again, with the old AMI this works and with the new AMI, it throws the same error.  Packet capture shows the same result.

Looking at the code differences in framework versions there are no changes to the System.Net.Security namespace between 5.0.5 and 5.0.7.

The odd thing here is that running this method using google.com with port 443 works with the new AMI.

I feel like something very small has changed in the AMI but I don't know how to find out what.  Remote debugging the core framework on linux isn't something I know how to do.

Comment: Do you have some other openssl version floating around that gets picked up in the broken environment?

Comment: @D.SM Not that I (or Amazon) can find.  The broken environment isn't changed from the stock AMI - I have rebuilt the servers and this is a repeatable process with a new image - all I have done is deploy the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB drivers including the C# one are open source, you should be able to put breakpoints or print statements into the driver to see whether it is explicitly selecting some TLS versons (it shouldn't unless you are configuring it as such).

Assuming the driver isn't doing that, the problem is in the image. Try `openssl s_client` to connect to your MongoDB servers from that image.

Comment: OpenSSL s_client return the same info (with TLS v1.2) from both environments.

With respect to the driver, it's the same version in both environments.  Both environments have exactly the same code.

Comment: Clearly something is different, so you'll need to get a debugger going and figure out what it is.

Comment: Do you mean there's differences in code?  Both environments pull the compiled code from the same s3 bucket.